# Do implicit move methods always preserve fundamental data?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy, move, move-semantics

It's my understanding that when a basic data type is moved from, it will always perform a copy.
For example, you can never move from an `int`, and have the original `int` value unspecified:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int x = 100;
    int y{std::move(x)};
    std::cout << x << " " << y; //always prints "100 100"

}
```

Does this mean that the same is true for basic data types inside user-defined types?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Foo{
    int i = 100;
    std::vector<int> vec={1,2,3,4,5}; //something that probably will have an invariant
};

int main() {

    Foo x;
    Foo y{std::move(x)};
    std::cout << x.i << " " << y.i; //always print "100 100"?

}
```

What does the standard say about retaining these fundamental type values after a move?

Comment: Why is there so much discussion of what you can do with a value that you've moved from? If you intend to use it after passing it somewhere, don't move it.

Comment: I completely agree with you.  I would still like to know.

Comment: @PeteBecker Moved-from objects are not destroyed.  There are many valid reasons to use them afterwards that do not preclude moving them.

Comment: @Yakk using the objects doesn't preclude moving them, but surely using the values (before they've been reassigned at which point this question becomes moot) of the moved object does preclude moving?

Comment: @user2079303 No, it does not?  Most `std` objects have a very defined state after being moved-from (admittedly, the fact that vector does not when *assigned-moved-from* sort of undermines my case).  The standard containers don't require much from moved-from objects, but generally when I write my objects I understand and specify the moved-from state.

Comment: @PeteBecker: so if Trevor is writing compiler optimisations, and he writes one that violates a guarantee in the standard about the post-condition of move, can he refer his users to you for a telling-off when they trip over it? ;-) Or to put it another way, is it a defect in the standard that it makes guarantees nobody should ever rely on?

Comment: @SteveJessop: If the standard guarantees that a moved-from `int` retains it's value, then yes, I think the standard should be changed (it's probably not a defect because I doubt they did it by accident).  My view is that a moved-from object should be treated as having an indeterminate value, and that doing anything other than destructing it, or assigning to it, is a mistake.

Comment: @SteveJessop - how many readers of SE are compiler implementors who ask about this because they need to write conforming optimizers?

Comment: @Yakk - please don't put words in my mouth. I said nothing about moved-from objects being destroyed, and that has nothing at all to do with what I said.

Comment: @PeteBecker If you don't want people to put words in your mouth, don't do that to others.  Where did I state you said "moved-from objects are destroyed"?  Sure, you could read it in; but your statement (if you intend to use it after passing it somewhere, don't move it) implies you should never use it, like you shouldn't use an object which is destroyed (whose lifetime has ended).  You should never use an object whose lifetime has ended, nor should you use an object whose state/behavior is unspecified.  An object whose state/behavior is specified is fine to use, even if "moved from".

Comment: @PeteBecker In short, you said: "Don't do that!".  I used the equivalent of "It won't kill you, and it is fun."  That response does *not* imply the first person said "it will kill you".  (And I'm aware that you did not actually state that I actually put words in your mouth; you just told me not to do it.  This amuses me.)

Comment: @PeteBecker: do you need to know how many there are before you can decide whether or not to staff that support line? ;-) Regardless of what the number is, are you saying that SE users have no legitimate interest in understanding the guarantees available in C++, or are you not saying that? It just seems odd to me that anyone would object to this kind of information being discussed and shared, unless (as Martin suggests) it's because the whole idea of guaranteeing it was a terrible mistake that should be countered.

Comment: @SteveJessop - sigh. My point is simply that the multitude of questions about the effect of moving from an object is **obviously** not from implementors asking for the semantics that their optimizers have to be aware of. I don't object to this information being discussed; I question the **actual importance** of it to the typical user who is asking about it.

Comment: The moved from `int` value could very well be in a "valid but unspecified state" (17.6.5.15) and still print as `100`.

Comment: @BoPersson `int` is not a "type defined in the C++ standard library".

Answer (score 3):

The special member functions that the compiler generates are specified as basically doing the corresponding operation on each of the class's members (and base classes).

So your `struct Foo`'s `i` is going to behave just like an `int` that was moved-from.  Ditto for the `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the move constructor of your data members. For example, the `std::vector`'s move constructor will *usually* leave your vector empty, but as you said, the state is unspecified.

The state of int will not be changed as they are trivially move constructible. The compiler will perform copy with trivially move constructible types. As @T.C. stated in the comments, this behaviour is required by the standard.

if you intent to use your class after it was moved from, consider implementing your own move constructor:

```
struct Foo {
    int i = 100;
    std::vector<int> vec={1,2,3,4,5};

    Foo(Foo&& foo) noexcept : i{std::move(foo.i)}, vec{std::move(foo.vec)} {
        foo.vec = {}; // ensure it's empty
        foo.i = 0; // ensure it's 0
    }
};
```

Comment: I think a compiler is entitled, if it so wishes, to generate code which modifies the "moved-from" `int`s. Of course, we might believe that the be a strange implementation, and no real compiler would ever do it, but it's still valid. I ask because I think you should avoid the word "should" in your answer - it implies (falsely?) that such behaviour is required by the standard.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid It is required.

Comment: Thanks for the conformation @T.C. . I'll update the answer.